# getting the className of added DOM node (mutationObserver)

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

I'm writing a simple userscript that will auto-hide a Facebook post if it contains a certain list of words. The core functionality works, but my `MutationObserver` doesn't seem to read the `className` of `mutation.addedNodes` properly. I loop through `mutation.addedNodes` and check if any of those elements have the class `userContentWrapper`, but the result of that test is always false -- even if the element does have the class.

```
var startObserver = function() {        
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {        
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {            
            var added = mutation.addedNodes;            
            for (var i = 0; i < added.length; i++) {                
                if (/\buserContentWrapper\b/.test(added[i].className)) {
                    processFilter(added[i]);
                }
            }
        });        
    });    
    var obj = {childList: true, subtree: true, attributes: true};
    observer.observe(document.documentElement, obj);
};
```

I can only assume that the observer is analyzing the added node before it's fully formed with all the attributes in place. How can I make the observer wait to process the node until it's fully complete? Or am I not understanding the problem?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some of the added nodes are containers so you should check their insides:

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(onMutation);
observer.observe(document, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
});

function onMutation(mutations) {
  const found = [];
  for (const { addedNodes } of mutations) {
    for (const node of addedNodes) {
      if (!node.tagName) continue; // not an element
      if (node.classList.contains('userContentWrapper')) {
        found.push(node);
      } else if (node.firstElementChild) {
        found.push(...node.getElementsByClassName('userContentWrapper'));
      }
    }
  }
  found.forEach(processFilter);
}
```

MutationObserver callback is executed as a microtask that blocks DOM and JS engine so try to make it fast, especially if it runs on a complex site such as facebook that generates lots of DOM mutations. This can be tested in devtools (<kbd>F12</kbd> key) profiler/timeline panels.

Comment: Doesn't adding `childList` and `subtree` to the observation parameters dig deeper automatically?

Comment: It does not *expand* what was added. For example, `someNode.appendChild(anotherNodeWith1000children)` won't be expanded, because it's just one operation.

Comment: Huh, I thought that was how `childList` worked, and then `subtree` would automatically search through all descendents. What is `subtree` actually doing, then?

Comment: Just what the docs say: `subtree` reports mutations of the descendants. One mutation may comprise adding or removing of many nodes via `insertAdjacentHTML` or other means. And `childList` makes the observer look at this activity. Without it the callback won't be executed in these cases.

Comment: there is an extra parenthesis here

Comment: Thank you!!  This saved me a bunch of headache.  One thing to note, in the `else if` shouldn't it be `node.getElementsByClassName()` instead of `node.getElementsByTagName()`?