# How do I use the MutationObserver to check for an element with class being added to body?

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

I've found the MutationObserver documentation to be rather confusing. I would like to observe the document body for when DIV elements having the class `superelement` are added to the DOM.

```
<div class="superelement" style="display:none;2"></div>
```

I've managed to glue this snippet together:

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(onMutation);
observer.observe(document, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
});

function onMutation(mutations) {
  const found = [];
  for (const { addedNodes } of mutations) {
    for (const node of addedNodes) {
      if (!node.tagName) {
        continue; // not an element
      } else {
        if (node.classList.contains('superelement')) {
          console.log(node)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there no cleaner way to iterate all elements that were added? I can imagine this being rather slow.

Comment: `const found = mutations.addedNodes.filter(node => node.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'div' && node.classList.contains('superelement'));` will give you all div tags with that classname from the addedNodes in your mutations event

Comment: Why would this be slower than any other method? Even if you had a DocumentFragment where you could querySelector, it would still basically do the same thing: ask every elements if it matches the selector. Besides, we don't deal with improving working codes just for the sake of making it a bit better. For this, there is [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) on the SE network.

Comment: 1) All performance-related concerns should be verified by measuring, there's no need to guess, see [Performance of MutationObserver to detect nodes in entire DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39332340) 2) Your code will miss nested elements, you also need to check the descendants, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38525456).

Answer (score 1):

I had do to some searching before I could find something that wasn't a total mess. You really only need to do two things; it is a lot easier when you have clean code to work with.

With the first the `MutationObserver` object will pass a `MutationRecord` object and a `MutationObserver` object (no third parameters) when the condition (in this case: `{childList: true}`) is met:

```
 const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutation_record,mutation_observer)
 {
  //Match your condition here:
  if (mutation_record[0] && mutation_record[0].addedNodes[0] && mutation_record[0].addedNodes[0] === id_('modal'))
  {
   //Do a jig.
  }
 });
```

To start the observation simply define the node as the first parameter and an object containing the conditions:

```
 observer.observe(tag_('body')[0], {childList: true});
```

Doing some quick research here is an exhuastive example of the second parameter's object:

```
{
 attributes: false,
 attributeOldValue: false,
 //attributeFilter: array,
 characterDataOldValue: false,
 childList: true,
 characterData: false,
 subtree: false,
}
```